# Config / .cfg / .ini file linked with c program

Tags: c, configuration, config, ini

I made program that helps with learning english. You have code below, but for my question you don't need to read and understand what's inside. What I want to do is to create .cfg or .ini file, that can be open with simple notepad and lets user modify:
MAX size (default is 15)
Sleep(x) value (default is 500)
I have no idea how can I make such config file that can be modified by user,link it with my c code, and then after runing program.exe it accepts changes from there. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define MAX 15 //word max size

struct slowa
{
    char pl_word[MAX];
    char eng_word[MAX];
};

void menu(void);
int count_lines(FILE*);
void print_array1 (const int[],int); //print 1-dimension array
void swap (int*,int*);

int main ()
{
    srand( time( NULL ) );
    int i,k,j;
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen ("tekst", "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        printf ("zjebales"); //"you fucked up"
        return -1;
    }
    const int lines = count_lines(fp);
    int tab[lines]= {};
    int* temp = (int*)malloc(lines*sizeof(int));
    for (j=0; j<lines; j++)
    {
        temp[j]=j+1;
    }
    j=lines;
    for (i=0; i<lines; i++)
    {
        k=rand()%j--;
        tab[i]=temp[k]-1;
        swap(temp+k,temp+j);
    }
    free(temp);
    struct slowa arr[lines];
    rewind (fp);
    for (i=0; i<lines; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%s %s", arr[tab[i]].pl_word, arr[tab[i]].eng_word);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    char text[MAX];
    k=0;
    system("cls");
    menu();
    scanf("%d",&j);
    system("cls");
    char ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);

    switch (j)
    {
    case 1:
        for (i=0; i<lines; i++)
        {
            printf ("Podaj tlumaczenie:%s\n", arr[i].eng_word); //"Write translation"

            //fgets (text, MAX, stdin);
            scanf ("%s",text);

            if (strcmp(arr[i].pl_word, text) == 0)
            {
                puts ("DOBRZE!"); //"Correct!"
                k++;
            }
            else puts ("ZLE!"); //"Wrong"
            Sleep(500);
            system("cls");
        }

        break;
    case 2:
        for (i=0; i<lines; i++)
        {
            printf ("Podaj tlumaczenie:%s\n", arr[i].pl_word); //"Write translation"
            scanf ("%s",text);

            if (strcmp(arr[i].eng_word, text) == 0)
            {
                puts ("DOBRZE!"); //Correct!
                k++;
            }
            else puts ("ZLE!"); //Wrong!
            Sleep(500);
            system("cls");
        }
        break;

    default:
        puts ("miales podac 1 lub 2 dzbanie"); //"You should put 1 or 2"
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }
    printf ("Odpowiedziales dobrze na %d/%d pytan. ", k, lines); //"You answered correctly k/lines words"
    if (k==lines) puts("No dobra cos tam umiesz");
    else if(k>(lines/2)&&k<lines) puts ("Mogloby byc lepiej");
    else puts ("Wracaj do nauki debilu");
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to link your program with the config file. Just read the file from your c program and than use the values from the file.

Comment: Do you want a change via notepad to have immediate effect or is it OK to have to explicitly trigger reading it in again? Or would it even be OK to restart the program?

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm not sure if i understand your question, but Benjamins answer seems to be useful